# vNext Server variables missing

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I get server variable in vNext? In ASP.NET I use:

```
Request.ServerVariables.Get("AUTH_USER")
```

In vNext ServerVariables in Context.Request is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServerVariables is a property bag of miscellaneous information. I don't expect it be added to vNext as is. We should look at the individual pieces of information your trying to find and where they can be accessed now.  For example, AUTH_USER roughly maps to HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to get user name from Active Directory when I turned on IIS Windows Authentication. In asp.net I recieved username through ServerVariables.Get("AUTH_USER"). HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is empty. But in IIS log is user name OK - id-karta\pavel.  `#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip`  `2014-09-16 06:57:29 ::1 GET /IDWare4 - 80 id-karta\pavel ::1`

Comment: CoreCLR or Classic/Desktop CLR? WindowsIdentity isn't working yet for CoreCLR.

Comment: You are right. When I switch CoreCLR to Classic CLR, Identity name is OK.